# AI Car Unity wrong rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my first post, so if I do something wrong, let me know it. Im doing in Unity 5.5 a 2D Car Game, with a topdown view. For the game, i need that some cars have a simple AI Script, just for follow a path. So, I searched in the web something that fits my needs, and found(in my opinion) a really good implementation. Here i let u the project in GitHub, uploaded by the owner of the implementation I suppose: https://github.com/mindcandy/lu-racer

So in a few words, we create a Path with empty GameObjects and the respective colliders, we have to have a car(obviously) and set up with a collider and a rigidbody2d, and we have three scripts that "do the magic". For my project, I remove the part of counting the laps because my game is not a race. Well, i set up all and everything works fine! Except for one thing: the car´s rotation.

I think this is happens because the tutorial game is a topdown view but cars go from left to right, and in my game is topdown also but cars go from down to up. So the cars's sprites in my project are in topdown view and looking to up, and the car's sprite of the github project are topdown view looking to right(i wanted upload the images but appears me that i cant do it due my reputation, sorry).

Definitely, the AI works really good and the car follow without problems the path, but with a wrong rotation, like this: [aicar_rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iXHH.png)

I tried changing things in the AICarMovement scripts related to the vectors, and angles, but without luck, so if anyone can look and give me a hand, I'll be grateful. If anyone wants more details for understand the problem, let me know. I try upload more things like pictures or gifs to show the problem, but i cant do it due the reputation.

This is the part of code in AICarMovement that i think i have to change:

```
public class AICarMovement : MonoBehaviour {
public float acceleration = 0.5f;
public float braking = 0.3f;
public float steering = 4.0f;
private Rigidbody2D rigidb;

Vector3 target;

void Start() {
    rigidb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

public void OnNextTrigger(TrackLapTrigger next){
    target = Vector3.Lerp(next.transform.position - next.transform.right, next.transform.position + next.transform.right, Random.value);
}

void steerTowardsTarget() {
    Vector2 towarNextTrigger = target - transform.position;
    float targetRot = Vector2.Angle(Vector2.right, towarNextTrigger);
    if(towarNextTrigger.y < 0.0f) {
        targetRot = -targetRot;
    }
    float rot = Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(transform.localEulerAngles.z, targetRot, steering);
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, rot);
}

void FixedUpdate(){
    steerTowardsTarget();
    float velocity = rigidb.velocity.magnitude;
    velocity += acceleration;
    rigidb.velocity = transform.right * velocity;
    rigidb.angularVelocity = 0.0f;
}
```

}

Sorry about my english, is not my native language.

Comment: Please try to include the relevant code in your question body - note that we don't need (or even want) the entire project, just the code that handles moving/rotating the car based on your waypoints. This site expects questions to be self-contained, meaning that all the information to solve the question should be in this post (ie. Don't rely on off-site links).

Comment: Yes, you are right, i realized  that after uploading the post. Im gonna edit the post including the relevant code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn your sprite and also the spawn game object. This way you have no fancy behaviour and all looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

In steerTowardsTarget(), 2nd line:
Try to change the first parameter of Angle() from Vector2.right to Vector2.up.

Comment: Hi! Yes, i tried this before, but is not working. The car goes crazy and does this: http://gph.is/2jW0yZm

Comment: Did you try just to turn your sprite? Or use an empty gameobject with your rotated car as a child? Ah wait. Did you change Vector2 **and** transform.right to .up in the 2nd last line?  And also the two transform.right in OnNextTrigger()

Comment: Yes, if i turn my sprite, works fine, but when a car spawns, appears rotated in scene and this dont look so elegant lol. Yes, i also tried to change the "right things" to up, but nothing. The car does not even go the way that way :(

Comment: If the car don't spawns the right way you can adjust the rotation from the spawn game object. I don't know the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt think that. I use the rotate sprite, but rotate the gameobject to let the right rotation, and now works fine! In the end it was simpler than I thought. Thank you so much! If you want the last comment put it as answer so i mark as the correct answer.

Comment: Glad i could help you :)